# Css loginsystem website

Tags: html, css

I need to float my columns on the right but I don't know how I can put them under each other with space between them. The CSS is linked to the HTML page some of the CSS is in the HTML page because I used google fonts for them.

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";


body {
 background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/5fHm9Kt.png");
}
.wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 float: right;
 width: 350px;
}
.wrapper2 {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:20px; 
 float: right;
 width: 350px;
}
.grid {
 display:block;
}
form{
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
signup-form input[type="text"] {
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 70%;
}
input{
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 width: 70%;
 padding: 5px;
}
signup-form input input[type="text"] {
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 70%;
}
button{
 display: center;
 padding: 5px;
 border: gray;
 background-color: light-gray;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
 .wrapper h2 { 
 color: #48B758;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius-top: 5px;
 border-color: silver;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
.wrapper2 h2 { 
 color: #48B758;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius-top: 5px;
 border-color: silver;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

button{
 display: center;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 75%; 
 background-color: light-gray;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
</style>
 
 <div class="grid">
   <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
   <h2>Registreer</h2>
            <form class="signup-form" id="signup-form" action="signup.inc.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Voornaam">
                <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Achternaam">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Account aanmaken</button>
            </form>          
      </div>
      <div id="wrapper2" class="wrapper2">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="voornaam">
            <input type="text" placeholder="achternaam">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
            <button type="submit" name="login">Login !</button>
            </form>         
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is already on right. What do you exactly want?

Comment: I want the register and the login wrapper to display under each other.

Comment: You mean one box for them

Comment: Look at it in "Full page" than you will see the problem im having.

Comment: Login and register looking up down..

Comment: what i understood. I posted answer please check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
 .wrapper h2 {  

  color: #48B758;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius-top: 5px;
  border-color: silver;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.wrapper2 h2 {  

  color: #48B758;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius-top: 5px;
  border-color: silver;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

button{
  display: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 75%; 
  background-color: light-gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


@charset "ISO-8859-1";


body {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/5fHm9Kt.png");
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto; 

  width: 350px;
}
.wrapper2 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:20px; 

  width: 350px;
}
.grid {
  float: right;
}
form{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
signup-form input[type="text"] {
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 70%;
}
input{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 5px;
}
signup-form input input[type="text"] {
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 70%;
}
button{
  display: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: gray;
  background-color: light-gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>

 <div class="grid">
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
        <h2>Registreer</h2>
        <form class="signup-form" id="signup-form" action="signup.inc.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Voornaam">
            <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Achternaam">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Account aanmaken</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper2" class="wrapper2">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="voornaam">
            <input type="text" placeholder="achternaam">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
            <button type="submit" name="login">Login !</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to remove the float="right" property from wrapper and wrapper2. Use this property in the grid class.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";


body {
 background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/5fHm9Kt.png");
}
.wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 20px 0; 
 float: right;
 width: 350px;
}
.wrapper2 {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:20px; 
 float: right;
 width: 350px;
}
.wrapper2 form{
padding-bottom: 59px;
}
.grid {
 display:block;
}
form{
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
signup-form input[type="text"] {
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 70%;
}
input{
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 width: 70%;
 padding: 5px;
}
signup-form input input[type="text"] {
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 70%;
}
button{
 display: center;
 padding: 5px;
 border: gray;
 background-color: light-gray;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
 .wrapper h2 { 
 color: #48B758;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius-top: 5px;
 border-color: silver;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
.wrapper2 h2 { 
 color: #48B758;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius-top: 5px;
 border-color: silver;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

button{
 display: center;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 75%; 
 background-color: light-gray;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
</style>
 
 <div class="grid">
   <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
   <h2>Registreer</h2>
            <form class="signup-form" id="signup-form" action="signup.inc.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Voornaam">
                <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Achternaam">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Account aanmaken</button>
            </form>          
      </div>
      <div id="wrapper2" class="wrapper2">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="voornaam">
            <input type="text" placeholder="achternaam">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
            <button type="submit" name="login">Login !</button>
            </form>         
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `clear` property for `wrapper2` class in your CSS

Per Mozilla Developer Documentation [Web technology for developers > CSS > **clear**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear):

> The `clear` CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them. The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements.

More specifically for the *floating* elements, as in this case:

> When applied to floating elements, it moves the margin edge of the element below the margin edge of all relevant floats. This affects the position of later floats, since later floats cannot be positioned higher than earlier ones.

You can achieve this by setting the clear property to either `both` or `right`, as follows--

```
.wrapper2 {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:20px; 
    float: right;
    width: 350px;
    clear:both;
}
```

Full demo posted on: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zd345qy1/)

```css
@charset "ISO-8859-1";


body {
 background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/5fHm9Kt.png");
}
.wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 float: right;
 width: 350px;
}
.wrapper2 {
 background-color: white;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:20px; 
 float: right;
 width: 350px;
  clear:both;
}
.grid {
 display:block;
}
form{
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
signup-form input[type="text"] {
 margin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 70%;
}
input{
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 width: 70%;
 padding: 5px;
}
signup-form input input[type="text"] {
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 70%;
}
button{
 display: center;
 padding: 5px;
 border: gray;
 background-color: light-gray;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

 .wrapper h2 { 
 color: #48B758;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius-top: 5px;
 border-color: silver;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
.wrapper2 h2 { 
 color: #48B758;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius-top: 5px;
 border-color: silver;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: lighter;
}

button{
 display: center;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 75%; 
 background-color: light-gray;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="grid">
     <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
     <h2>Registreer</h2>
        <form class="signup-form" id="signup-form" action="signup.inc.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Voornaam">
            <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Achternaam">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Account aanmaken</button>
        </form>          
     </div>
     <div id="wrapper2" class="wrapper2">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="voornaam">
          <input type="text" placeholder="achternaam">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
          <button type="submit" name="login">Login !</button>
        </form>         
      </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```